# Javascript issue with if statements

Tags: javascript

ive wrote a simple script that isnt working as intentioned:

```
var prevscroll = 0;
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var currscroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(currscroll > prevscroll){
        $("header").toggle();
        prevscroll = currscroll;
    }
    if(currscroll < prevscroll){
        $("header").toggle();
        prevscroll = currscroll;
    }
});
```

When the page is scrolled down, its meant to hide the header and only show it if its scrolled up however whats happening is as i scroll down its flicking on and off. :|

I think I may of just spotted a silly error! ofcourse its going to keep flickering since prev scroll keeps increasing.

Comment: every time that condition returns true you are toggling the appearance causing it to flash. You need to specify either `hide()` or `show()` depending on if you are scrolling up or down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `toggle()` the way you are because the scroll event is called many, many times so if it's called more than once with the same value for your `if` statement, then it will flicker on, then off, then on, then off each time you call `.toggle()`.  You need to explicitly hide or show when your condition is met.

I don't quite follow exactly what you're trying to do with `prevscroll`, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
var prevscroll = 0;
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var currscroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(currscroll > prevscroll){
        $("header").hide();
        prevscroll = currscroll;
    }
    if(currscroll < prevscroll){
        $("header").show();
        prevscroll = currscroll;
    }
});
```

This will hide the header anytime you are scrolling down further and show the header as soon as you start to scroll up.

Comment: Doh, I kind of caught on after I posted! Thanks for answering

Comment: Im using prevscroll to test which direction is being scrolled to hide nav bar on mobiles when scrolling down, but then showing when scrolling up instead of having a static bar right at the top. (if that made sense)